# Scope of class variable in admin helper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, scope

I need to access a variable from one method in the admin helper from another method in the admin helper. Defining a instance variable won't work. The scope of a global variable is definitely to wide (I only need access in admin helper). Hence I was wondering if I could achieve that using a class variable (@@). Or is the scope here to wide again? If so, what would be the correct way to limit the scope?

Comment: Why won't defining an instance variable work?

Answer (score 0):

Normally instance variable should be available in one class. So i guess the method you are using are singleton method which is "def self.method"

Instance variable are not available in singleton method, unless you use class instance variable.

```
class A
  @class_instance_vari = 0
  def self.a
    p "class instance vari is #{@class_instance_vari}"
    p "instance vari is #{@instance_vari} #"
  end

  def self.b
    p "class instance vari is #{@class_instance_vari}"
    p "instance vari is #{@instance_vari} #"
  end

  def initialize(*args)
    @instance_vari = 0
  end
end
```

A.a and A.b will output

```
class instance vari is 0
instance vari is #
```

Basically class instance variable has the same scope with class variable. class instance variable will not have the same value in sub classes, while class variable will always contain the same value in all sub classes.